# protecting electrical wires below 8' in open framing garage

Tags: electrical

how do I protect electrical wires run horizontally below 8' in open framing garage? its all done already, I have lots of scrap plywood and 2x4s, I was hoping to run horiz plywood strips 6" wide for protection.

Comment: Hello, and welcome  to Home Improvement. A picture or diagram would really help us here.

Comment: Even though two people have answered, your question is a little broad. When you speak of conductors (wires) are you talking about a cable system?  Is it something like NM or UF or just individual conductors. Note that each system has a separate dedicated chapter and tells you what you can and can't do and how to protect it.

Answer (score 1):

Code allows wires in the stud bays below 8'  to be protected with 1/2" sheetrock or plywood. Since you are talking a horizontal run I am not sure if 6" strip would be legal because you could still access the wire, I usually cover the entire wall.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are describing an electrical run dropping down from a top plate and running along a wall through holes in framing to supply a GFCI outlet -- perhaps for a water softener or landscaping clock or similar garage outlet?

My question would be "protection" from what? If you are concerned you might accidentally shear the wire with a tool, then certainly one option is to drywall the wall in question. If you want to "waterproof" the electrical circuit so you can do a wet hobby in your garage, then flexible conduit is the better answer.

You'll need a run of 1/2" flexible conduit, a contractor's bag of terminator connections for the conduit connection into the junction boxes, and a bag of EMT 1-hole mounting straps for restraining the conduit along existing framing.

You have to isolate the garage circuit at the breaker; disconnect all the wires at the end where they meet the receptacle box; carefully pull the wires back out of the wall; carefully thread new conduit into the wall holes; trim the conduit to the finished length at the receptacle; finish the conduit by using squeeze-end threaded connectors and secure them into the receptacle; then re-thread the electrical wire through the conduit to the receptacle and reconnect the wires to the outlet.

(I know that was a very abridged summary)

There are numerous video examples out there on "installing flexible electrical conduit" if you choose to go this way.

Remember local electrical codes vary from place to place, so it makes sense to just call an electrician and ask them for a quote, then at least you will know what they propose and how much.